# System.IO.IOException: The symbolic link cannot be followed because its type is disabled

Tags: c#

What does this mean exactly?  I'm doing something like this:

```
File.Copy(@"\\foo\bar\baz.txt", @"c:\test\baz.txt");
```

MSDN doesn't describe this exception except in general terms, and googling around just yields tables of error codes.

I've confirmed the source file exists, and I'm 99% sure that I have the permissions to copy the file to the destination location.

Comment: What is your destination folder?  Is it an actual folder on the file system, or a symlink (junction in NTFS) to another location?

Comment: The destination folder is a local folder.

I discovered that the source file is a symlink to another location on the same system (\\foo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this article for some information about using symlinks in .Net: "[Manipulating NTFS Junction Points in .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/JunctionPointsNet.aspx)".

According to this article:

> "In particular the .NET libraries does
>   not include any functionality for
>   creating or querying properties of
>   Junction Points"

But there is a method how to actually get the target of the symlink, and then you'll be able to use File.Copy with it.

Answer (score 1):

By default local evaluation of remote symbolic links is disabled.

You could use fsutil to change that setting or you could delve into unmanaged code and resolve the link yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You will get this error if the destination file already exists. I would also confirm that the account you're running the code under has access to the UNC \foo\bar\baz.txt